# How do I get the key value when retrieving local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am using HTML5 and local storage to set / retrieve key/value pairs.

To set the value:

```
localStorage.setItem("003o000000BTRXz", "MyValue");
```

Then I utilized a function to loop through all stored items

```
for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  var obj = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
  alert(obj);
}
```

The result is "MyValue" and I would like it to be "003o000000BTRXz".

What would be the proper syntax to get this?

Comment: You mean... `localStorage.key(i)`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `localStorage.key(i)` to get the key:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var key   = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);

    alert(key + ": " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All browsers, especially the old ones might sometimes not support localstorage api included in HTML5. Thus it is advisable to first check if your browser supports it like so,

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
// Have fun with localstorage! :)
} else {
// alert something saying doesn't support
}
```

Use the localstorage api like so,

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("key", "Value");
// Retrieve
localStorage.getItem("key");
```